# Struct Dot Issue

Tags: c

I have a struct variable "accounts" and when reading in user input I come across these similar issues, which I feel as if the fix would be the same for each. However, I can't put my finger on what "expression" goes before "accounts" or ".". Any ideas as to what the issue is and how to fix it?

```
>main.c: In function âmainâ:
>main.c:143:18: error: expected expression before âaccountsâ
 scanf("%s", &accounts.first[0]);
>main.c:146:18: error: expected expression before âaccountsâ
 scanf("%s", &accounts.middle[0]);
              ^
>main.c:149:18: error: expected expression before âaccountsâ
 scanf("%s", &accounts.last[0]);
              ^
>main.c:179:28: error: expected expression before â.â token
 scanf("%d", &(accounts).accountBalance);
                        ^
>main.c:180:13: error: expected identifier or â(â before â.â token
 accounts.accountNum = tempAccNum;
         ^
>main.c:182:28: error: expected expression before âaccountsâ
 accList[numAccounts] = accounts;
```

Here is where I declared the struct if this will help:

```
typedef struct accounts
{
    char first[20];
    char middle[2];
    char last[20];
    int accountNum;
    int accountBalance;
} accounts;
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code.

Comment: Note: Be sure the quote marks in `"%s"` are not [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Smart_quotes).  Post looks OK, but true code may differ.

Comment: I included the code @ChristianGibbons

Comment: `accounts` is just the definition of your struct.  You need to create a variable of type `accounts`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons so if i declared a variable of type accounts = t; Then for my issues with compiler it'd be something like t.accountNum = tempAccNum ??

Comment: you'd declare `t` as type accounts the same way you might an int: `accounts t;`  And then, yes, you'd assign to `t` such as `t.accountNum = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler obviously doesn't think `accounts` and `(accounts)` are expressions, which leads me to suspect that there's a type called `accounts`. If that's the case, all you need to do is rename either the type or the variable.